# How to integration test AWS EC2 execution of a user data script on launch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tmux

I have a Node app which uses the [AWS EC2 Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) to programmatically create a new instance. I [pass a UserData script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) into the params so that the script will be run on instance launch. The script downloads some files and run some apps in [tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/).

I have unit tests on the code in my Node app launching the instance. But how can I integration test this from my Node app so that the actual execution of the script on the instance is tested?

I want to test whether the state of the entire system, including the running apps in tmux panes, meets my test assertion. Is this even possible?